# Azure Cosmos Db 429 retry policy with Entity Framework Core

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

To do retries if my requests have more than the max number of RUS by using Azure Cosmos API client I need to implement a retry policy by myself ( by using Polly for example). 
If I use EF Core provider with Cosmos DB are some retries included in ef provider implementation? How to configure it?